# Removing a particular pattern of a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, file

I have an input file named file1 which contains:

> Student 0 : Performed well but can do better. [76.50%]
>
> Student 1 : Brilliant performance. [98.50%]

In this particular file I just want to remove the % part so that it produces output like:

> Student 0 : Performed well but can do better.
>
> Student 1 : Brilliant performance.

I tried in this manner:

```
with open('file1', 'r') as infile, open('file2', 'w') as outfile:
    temp = infile.read().replace("[[0-9]+]", "").replace("%","")
    outfile.write(temp)
```

But this is only removing the %sign and giving output as:

> Student 0 : Performed well but can do better. [76.50]
>
> Student 1 : Brilliant performance. [98.50]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need regex:

```
import re
with open('file1', 'r') as infile, open('file2', 'w') as outfile:
    temp = re.sub("\[[\d+\.%]+\]", "", infile.read())
    outfile.write(temp)
```

Comment: It is giving a warning saying : "FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
  temp = re.sub("[[0-9]+]", "", infile.read()).replace("%","")"

Comment: @Dev Check my edit

Comment: Yes, thanks. Now I am getting my desired output but that future warning is still there. Can you help?

Comment: @Dev Check my edit